# When should we use the advanced parameters of save()?

Tags: sql, django, database, django-models, model

Normally we save an instance into the database simply with `inst.save()`, but Django uses `user.save(using=self._db)` in [its source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L148). Also, it uses `user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])` [elsewhere](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L21).

This somewhat confuses me. To make things worse, the [document for the `save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) is *extremely* simple:

> `Model.save(force_insert=False, force_update=False,
>   using=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS, update_fields=None)`[[source]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/db/models/base/#Model.save)
>
> If you want customized saving behavior, you can override this `save()`
>   method. See [Overriding predefined model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) for more details.
>
> The model save process also has some subtleties; see the sections
>   below.

It doesn't even contain the explanation of those parameters!

My question is: how do I know when I should use the advanced parameters of `save()`? If I'm implementing a custom model, I would definitely write `user.save()`.

I've done a couple of experiments myself, like change `user.save(using=self._db)` to `user.save()`, and nothing went wrong, but I don't want to be surprised someday. Also, the parameters must be passed for some reasons, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is you will know when you need to :)
For now resort to this practice

class MyModel(models.Model):

```
def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
   # do whatever
   super(MyModel,self).save(*args,**kwarags)
```

This way you make sure that you don't accidentally drop any of those mysterious, parameters. But let's try to demystify some of them.

### using=self._db

This is to facilitate the use of multible databases in a single django app. Which most apps don't really need.

### update_fields

> If save() is passed a list of field names in keyword argument
>   update_fields, only the fields named in that list will be updated.
>   This may be desirable if you want to update just one or a few fields
>   on an object. There will be a slight performance benefit from
>   preventing all of the model fields from being updated in the database

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/

So the link to the source code is a specific instance where they have used this feature. Quite useful to keep track of when a user logged in for the last time without updating the entire record.

### force_insert vs force_update

These tell django to try forcing one or the other operation. Also explained to some extent in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/

Answer (score 1):

The example of `user.save(using=self._db)` I believe is redundant when you only have one db, usually defined as "default
. This example simply points out that if you have multiple dbs, you can pass in which of multiple dbs to use when saving.

Answer (score 0):

`update_fields` is also handy when you keep a reference to an instance for a long time (for example in a middleware) and the data might be changed from somewhere else. In these cases you either have to perform a costly `refresh_from_db()` on the instance to get the newest data from the database, or when you only want to override specific attributes you can omit the `refresh_from_db()` call and just use `save(update_fields=['attr1', 'attr2'])`. This will leave all other attributes unchanged in the database except for the ones you specified. If you omit `update_fields` in this case all values would be overwritten in the database with the values of your cached reference to the instance, leading to information loss.